# Unit testing complex object graphs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, repository-pattern, service-layer

Imagine an asp.net mvc application of moderate complexity that uses the repository pattern with a service layer.  Now imagine we have some behavior with a broad range of dependencies.  Take a contrived example: the CustomerController needs to display customers which match all of the following criteria:

- customers billing or shipping address is in Florida
- customer is in the VIP club  (using ClubMembershipService)
- customer has at least one previous order
- customer owns at least one car with model year 2005 or newer
- the car has a part that's been recalled
- and so on, with a few more one-to-manies or 3rd party API calls

Each test of this scope requires an immense amount of seed/mock data.  My next test is likely to require a similar, but significantly different set of data.  Let's say that any test at the controller level will require injecting 6 services, and in turn 8 repositories into those services.

How can I keep my tests manageable?  How can I navigate a deep object graph and ensure that the mock (or concrete) repositories supply valid, consistent data without 30 lines of setup code in each test?

e.g. If this were a pure integration test using a test database, I might need the following:

- a few customer records
- a few address records; some customers with multiple address records; one whose shipping address is in Florida; one whose billing address is in Florida
- a few orders
- some "CustomerCar" records; one of the cars should have model year 2005 or newer
- Some "CarPartRecall" records; some of these would match the make, model and year of the CustomerCar records
- and so on for additional criteria/logic

I understand that it might make sense to attach these criteria to the Customer object as properties, as in customer.IsInVipClub.  I'm more interested in the complex cases that don't translate to simple properties because they cross multiple aggregate boundaries.  e.g. customer.Owns2005OrNewerCarWithRecalledParts is a property I wouldn't typically write.

AutoFixture was suggested.  It looks like a cross between a mocking framework and a fixture factory (as in factoryGirl for rails).  I think it would make the initialization code more terse by auto-supplying some property values such as customer.firstName, but it feels like a relatively small gain.  I'd be interested to hear anybody's experience with AutoFixture.

Comment: This question might benefit from a concrete example.  To me it sounds like a design problem, not a unit testing problem.  If you have to interact with 6 services and 8 repositories in the same method, then the method is most likely doing to much.

Comment: I thought I provided a concrete example.  In the example, data is required from many different aggregate roots. e.g. CustomerService, AddressService ClubMembershipService, OrderService, CarService, etc.  Maybe I wasn't clear - in the example, the controller should only display customers that match ALL of the criteria in my bulleted list.

Comment: I think I was unclear.  I meant a code example.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could do that, but as I said, the example is contrived.  In my head, the Repositories have simple Add(), Delete(), and Find() methods.  The services are wrappers around the repositories, providing logic where necessary.  e.g. CarService.GetRecalledParts(make, model, year).

Comment: Have you checked out AutoFixture: http://autofixture.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's interesting.  Thanks for the link.  It does appear to be trying to solve the same problem.  I'll flesh out the OP with a bit more detail.

Comment: I asked similar question to Google and appeared here. Well, good to know we are not alone in the IT Universe with the same issue. Well, I hesitate whether I need everywhere to setup a mock. I wrote in-memory repository and guess what? Covered it with unit tests=) Then I use it in my tests of other services and domain objects. Effortful? Sure, but more maintainable, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like a *simple* query, there's no value in testing it. Not everything needs to be united tested.

If you really want to test this you can do as an integration test. Set up a test database, preferably in memory, insert your dummy data, run your queries asserting the result and delete the dummy data. Repeat for every test.

For 3rd party API calls, there's no other way besides mocking them.

It's still a lot of work, but some tests are harder to do and requires more work to build.

Remember, unit tests need to run fast. If they start to take longer to run, they'll be ran less often. On the other side, integration tests can be ran from time to time and can take more time.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a "simple" query.  I can imagine so many different ways for this code to fail.  If we don't test it, how do we know it works?

Comment: Please don't take _simple_ as easy or unimportant, but in the end it's just a query, there's no way and no value in unit testing pure data retrieval methods. If this is a core to your business, by all means go ahead an test it, but test the important part: the data retrieval. Setup a test database, populate it with data and run the queries.

Comment: I understand what you mean by "simple" now, but I feel like 95% of my application logic is "just a query", by this definition.  I'm beginning to think that integration tests are simply better for the data-centric LOB apps I work on.  They still require a lot of setup though.

Comment: I feel your pain. I too work on a very intensive data-centric application and although we don´t have as many integration tests as we'd like (just a few dozen) they have proven to be invaluable to prevent bugs.